# Simple Regex pattern unmatched with Flex/Bison (Lex/Yacc)

Tags: grammar, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I have built a trivial compiler using Flex and Bison which is supposed to recognize a simple string in a source file and I use the standard error stream to output a message if the string is recognized correctly.

Below is my code and my unexpected result.

This is the source file (`testsource.txt`) with the string I try to recognize:

```tex
\end{document}
```

This is the Flex file (`UnicTextLang.l`):

```c
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"
    void yyerror(char *);
    int yylex(void);
    /* "Connect" with the output file  */
    extern FILE *yyout;
    extern int  yyparse();
%}

%%

^\\end\{document\}$ { yyerror("end matched"); return END; }

    /* skip whitespace */
[ \t] ;

    /* anything else is an error */
. yyerror("invalid character");

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if ( argc < 3 )
        yyerror("You need 2 args: inputFileName outputFileName");
    else {
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        yyout = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        yyparse();
        fclose(yyin);
        fclose(yyout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the Bison file (`UnicTextLang.y`):

```c
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"
    void yyerror(char *);
    int yylex(void);

    /* "Connect" with the output file  */
    extern FILE *yyout;
%}

%token END

%%

document:
        END
        |
        ;

%%

int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s); /* Prints to the standard error stream */
}
```

I run the following commands:

```
flex UnicTextLang.l
bison -dl -o y.tab.c UnicTextLang.y
gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o UnicTextLang
UnicTextLang.exe testsource.txt output.txt
```

What I expect to see printed in the console is

```
end matched
```

But this is what I get:

```
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
invalid character
```

What’s wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what system you are using? Is it windows, linux, OSX? This makes a difference for line end matching (see flex manual). We can then reproduce your issue and then answer....

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I am using Windows. Yes the issue is with line end matching. I tried adding a new line at the end of my source file and it works fine. It seems $ matches new line but not end of file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by the end-of-line code for a Windows machine being two characters (\r\n) when on other systems it is one  (\n).

This is explained in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns):

> ‘r$’
>   an ‘r’, but only at the end of a line (i.e., just before a newline). Equivalent to ‘r/\n’.
>
> Note that flex’s notion of “newline” is exactly whatever the C compiler used to compile flex interprets ‘\n’ as; in particular, on some DOS systems you must either filter out ‘\r’s in the input yourself, or explicitly use ‘r/\r\n’ for ‘r$’.

The quick solution is to change:

```
^\\end\{document\}$
```

to

```
^\\end\{document\}\r\n
```

However, if your expression is at the end-of-file without an end-of-line, which is possible in Windows, then you would have to specifically match that case also. Flex does permit the matching of end-of-file with:

```
<<EOF>>
```

but this will cause all kinds of other side effects and it is often easier not to anchor the pattern to the end (of line or file).

Comment: This is definitely the problem but your fix doesn't work. $ actually matches end-of-line fine. The problem is that neither $ nor \r\n actually match end-of-file. I don't know if there is a way to match end-of-file but I have changed it to just ^\\end\{document\} which seems to work for now

Comment: @hb20007 Yes; I added some text about that to make the answer more complete.